# How to keep one page of a site secure using mod_rewrite

Tags: virtualhost, mod-rewrite, https

I'd like redirect access to a url from http to https for only a couple of pages on my website.

I know how to do it for a whole site using the rewrite in apache virtual hosts:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But is there a way to do it for one page of the site? E.g. "www.example.com/protected-page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`RewriteRule ^/protected-page/(.*) https://example.com/protected-page/$1 [R,L]`

reference : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something different, and secured everything *but* a page that didn't work if it was protected:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*loadFormImages.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  #RewriteLog /opt/tmp/rewrite.log
  #RewriteLogLevel 3
```